# Same gravatar is displayed for different users in stackexchange.com filters

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, gravatar, tag-filters

Same gravatar is displayed for different users in the stackexchange.com [filters page](https://stackexchange.com/filters/118502), under the **Top Network Askers** in the right side bar.

The red circled image's source (`<img src=`) are from

```
https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/?s=18&d=identicon&r=PG&s=30
                               ^
```

Seems the gravatar id is missing here in the image source.

For an example from the list, the user [**Mad Scientist**'s](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/66c66c4d97a7bc3859a85253f003e1fb?s=18&d=identicon&r=PG&s=30) gravatar id should be

```
 https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/66c66c4d97a7bc3859a85253f003e1fb?s=18&d=identicon&r=PG&s=30
```

but it is mapped with

```
https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/?s=18&d=identicon&r=PG&s=30
```

which caused the display issue.

> [image: Same gravatar]